# Remove trailing blank line from TextBox

Tags: c#, textbox

I am reading in files via File.ReadAllText into a stringbuilder.  I am doing some replacements and regex, and then assigning it to textBox1.text.  I then use Lines.Distinct() to remove duplicates.  The result is perfect, expect there is one extra blank line (where the cursor is) at the end.  I do not want this blank line, and want it removed so the textbox ends at the last line of text, not on a new blank line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple solution would be to [`Trim()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx) the string before assigning it as the value of the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `.Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))`

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be assigning to `Lines` instead and using `File.ReadAllLines`, just for efficiency:

```
TextBox1.Lines = File.ReadAllLines(myFile).Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).Distinct().ToArray();
```

Comment: I am adding multiple files, not just one, I have a foreach loop.  Also, the blank line does not seem to be coming from the file, I made a test file with no trailing lines and deleted all empty space and still adds a blank line to the the textbox.

Comment: @Michael: Does assigning to `Lines` instead fix it?